# Python mechanize: read table element next to input

Tags: python, webforms, mechanize

I'm using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to fill out a form that has a series of rows. Each row is an `<input type="checkbox">` followed by `<td>name of the checkbox</td>`. How do I read the name so I know whether to check the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using both mechanize and etree, but I'm no programmer, so don't take my word for it.  Note: all code is in python, and is ver 2.7.1 but should work up to 2.7.3.

Hope I could help
        -Just another Dunce

```
import mechanize
import lxml.etree as etree

url = 'something'

br = mechanize.Browser()
resp = br.open(url)
parser = etree.parser()
tree = etree.parse(resp,parser)
forms = list(br.forms())
id_info = {}
for form in forms:
    elements = form.controls
    for element in elements:
        id_info[element.attrs['id']]=''

inputs = tree.findall('.//input')
for i in inputs:
    index = list(i.getparent()).index(i)
    id_info[i.attrib['id']] = list(i.getparent)[index+1]

for j in id_info:
    print j,id_info(j)
```